# Allowed memory size of {} bytes exhausted при чтении списка файлов

Tags: php, yii2, память, миграция

Есть список sql файликов, которые необходимо загрузить в базу.
Пользуюсь yii2 и его миграциями.

В папке лежит 10-15 файлов каждый по 6-9 Мб.

Бегу по ним и выполняю каждый друг за другом.

Загружаются почти все файлы и вылетает ошибка о том, что память закончилась.

Я предполагаю, что после чтения очередного файлика память не чистится, но могу ошибаться. Прошу помочь.

Вот скрипт:

```
class m180619_114125_fill_base extends Migration
{
    protected $filesDir = '/dumps/data/';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function safeUp()
    {
        $filesDir = Yii::getAlias('@console'.$this->filesDir);
        $globMask = $filesDir.'*.sql';
        $files = glob($globMask);
        if (!$files) {
            echo "Файлы для импорта базы не найдены\n";
            return false;
        }

        foreach ($files as $filePath) {
            $this->importFile($filePath);
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function safeDown()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /* HELPERS */

    protected function importFile($filePath)
    {
        $file = fopen($filePath, "r");
        $this->execute(fread($file, filesize($filePath)));
        fclose($file);
    }
}
```

Comment: У Вас режим какой? Если разработки то нужно отключать отладку `defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);` в index.php, память у Вас съедает скорее всего сам Yii и его профилирование-логирование

Comment: Надо метод up использовать.  Когда saveUp, тогда все загружается в бд, а потом исполняется.  Похоже бд всю память забирает и пыху уже ничего не остается.

Comment: @fedornabilkin, попробовал. не помогло. Думал может быть какой-то файлик на пару килобайт больше чем дозволено. Положил в начало загрузки самый тяжелый. Он прогружается. Но все равно ошибка. Примерно на том же количестве записей в базу

Comment: Можно попробовать обработать только половину файлов и выйти из форича. Если прокатит без ошибок, то я бы сделал второй файл миграции, чтоб им обработать вторую половину файлов. Или указать явно через константу в первой миграции, сколько файлов она будет отрабатывать и во второй также.

Answer (score 0):

```
class m180619_114125_fill_base extends Migration
{
    protected $filesDir = '/dumps/data/';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function safeUp()
    {
        $filesDir = Yii::getAlias('@console'.$this->filesDir);
        $globMask = $filesDir.'*.sql';
        $files = glob($globMask);
        if (!$files) {
            echo "Файлы для импорта базы не найдены\n";
            return false;
        }

        foreach ($files as $filePath) {
            $this->importFile($filePath);
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function safeDown()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /* HELPERS */

    protected function importFile($filePath)
    {
        $file = fopen($filePath, "r");
        $this->execute(fread($file, filesize($filePath)));
        fclose($file);
        unset($file);
    }
}
```

Comment: это не панацея) надо разобраться что есть память.

Comment: а при чем тут панацея ? вдруг у вас мемори лимит стоит 8мб, и файл который не считывается весит больше.

Comment: все файлы по 8-9 мб. 10 из 15 файлов читаются. размер у них одинаковый. я даже последние файлы, что не читаются, разбил еще на более мелкие.

Comment: я исправил свой ответ, вы же память с $file не освобождаете

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло. Я думаю php сам чистит память переменных на выходе из метода